# how to fire selection event in a IE HTML editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor

Here's part of code from a IE HTML editor:

```
var selectStr = [];
selectStr.push("img[control_type='video']");
$(selectStr[0], document).selectionchange(function() {
    alert();
}); // Explorer error: does not support this method or object.
    // It seems JQuery does not support 'selectionchange' event.


document.onselectionchange = function(){
    alert();
} // this works for all elements in the editor.
```

Can it be applied only to a particular element? I tryied:

```
$(selectStr[0], document).onselectionchange = function(){
    alert();
} // does not fire when selected.

alert($(selectStr[0], document)); // [object, object]
```

if `$(selectStr[0], document)` is changed to `SOMETHING` so that it alerts `[object, HTMLImgElement]`, the problem will be solved. Anyone knows how to do it in a correct way?

Comment: the answer is `$("img[control_type='video']", document)[0]`. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend you have to use the event "**onselectstart**" event in the internet explorer and for firefox u have to use "**ondragstart**" events to find the selection event.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: document.onselectionchange = function(){
    alert();
} // this works for all elements in the editor.

Comment: Can it be applied only to a particular element? I use `$(selectStr[0], document)` to replace `document` but it does not work.

Comment: I think so. It can be applied to particular elements. Try placing the image within a div and apply the event to the div.

Comment: `ondragstart` will not help you for selections made via the keyboard or using the "Select all" option in the context and edit menus.